# How to prove simple function is measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, simple-functions

I'm  aware of the definition of the measurable function. But I was wondering how to prove simple function is measurable? It would be better have some detailed proof.

Answer (score 11):

Consider a simple function
$$
f = \sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{E_i},
$$
where $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ are disjoint measurable sets. To see that $f$ is measurable, it suffices to show that
$$
f^{-1}(-\infty,a]
$$
is measurable for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
Given $a\in\mathbb{R}$, note that
$$
f^{-1}(-\infty,a] = \bigcup\{E_i \mid i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\ \text{such that}\ a_i\le a\}
$$
is a union of measureable sets. Therefore $f$ is measurable.

Comment: It could happen that $x \in D =\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} E_{i}\right)^{c}$. In this case we have that $f(x) = 0$. If $a \geq 0$, we would have $f^{-1} (- \infty, a] = \cup \{E_{i} \mid i \in \{1, \dots, n\} \text{ such that } a_{i} \leq a\} \cup D$.